# Font Awesome not working when binding icon in Angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

I have created a div which content is editable. The user can insert a phone number just by pressing a button click; The whole process is working, but the main issue is with phone icon inserted using font awesome library. The span appears normally except the icon which when binding is applied, thus the same
span appears and icon is displayed successfully when html page is loaded.

How can I solve this issue and make icons appear successfully if they are bind? Note multiple spans can be added (there are many others for Location and Web URL).

My example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/font-awesome-demo-onmog5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular-fontawesome specifically, but rather a misunderstanding of how Angular works. Please see *Angular markup* section of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089093/1377864 and dig up from there to learn about potential solutions: ng-template, ComponentFactoryResolved, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the method dynamically to force icon rendering. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8v4ux-cbgknf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is working example.

Comment: And how it is supposed to work for an editable content div ?